# Jquery Many autocompletes on the same page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implements the autocomplete function of Jquery on a formulary made on a jsp.

I have no problems for one textarea, but impossible to do that with many of them.

This is the codes of my page:
I use pushs to create the lists cause datas are imported from a java bean. This code is the result of the page creation after running the application and caught with CTRL-U.

```
        <script>
        $(function()
        {
            var TagsEntis = new Array();

                TagsEntis.push("MAIRIE");

                TagsEntis.push("COMMUNAUTE URBAINE");

                <!--Others pushs here-->

            $( "#tagsentis" ).autocomplete({source: TagsEntis});
        });
        </script>
        <script>
        $(function()
        {
            var TagsNames = new Array();

                TagsNames.push("CAPILLON");

                TagsNames.push("DUFOUR");

                TagsNames.push("STARON");

                <!--Others pushs here-->

            $( "#tagsnames" ).autocomplete({source: TagsNames});
        });
        </script>
```

And after the definition of the textareas using these tags:

```
           <form method="post" action="form.htm" name="formulary">
                <table id="formulary">
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            Entity
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="PersonForm.entity">
                                <input id="tagsentis" type="text" name="entity"
                                       value=""/>
                            </spring:bind>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            LastName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <spring:bind path="PersonForm.lastname">
                                <input id="tagsnames" type="text" name="lastname"
                                       value=""/>
                            </spring:bind>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

This code works, but just for the LastName Textarea.

Can you help me please?

Thank you so much in advance ;)

Comment: Have you looked at the console and checked for any errors? From what I can see both should work no problem. Though you would save space if you defined your arrays as var TagsNames = ["CAPILLON","DUFOUR","STARON",...]; Rather than declaring a new Array and pushing each element onto the array.

Comment: Dou you use this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ autocomplete plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I just found the problem: arguments are dynamically imported from java beans. But someof them are very longs and are put on many lines on the generated html page, which create an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a [demo of 2 autocomplete input-fields](http://jsfiddle.net/d4tjZ/)  (not textarea) here. 
Could you give es more datails how it is not working. Do you get any errors in the [java-script console](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/)

```
$(function() {
    var availFirstNames = [
        "Adam", "Anna", "Anita",
        "Bert", "Bob", "Chuck", "Claudia", "Douche", "Ernie",
        "Gib", "Henry", "Jesus", "John", "Lisp", "Perl",
        "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
    ];
    var availLastNames = availFirstNames;
    $( "#FirstName" ).autocomplete({
        source: availFirstNames
    });
    $( "#LastName" ).autocomplete({
        source: availLastNames
    });        
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Names: </label>
    <input id="FirstName" />
    <input id="LastName" />
</div>​
```