# Jquery autocomplete not working for dynamic fields

Tags: html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am new to jquery

I used the auto complete code from `http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight`

It is working fine for normal condition. For dynamically created fields ,

I changed the code as  by using (`on` and `live` method)

```
$(".searchInput").on("keydown.autocomplete", function() {
  source: availableTags
});
```

But it is not working for static fields too...

Below is my code

Script:

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
];


$(".searchInput").on("keydown.autocomplete", function() {
  source: availableTags
});

    });

      $( "#tag2" ).blur(function() {
      $('#myTabContent').append(
      '<input id="field"  name="tags[]"  type="text"    class="searchInput"   />');
      });
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <form role="form" class="add_client_popup">
    <input type="text"  id="tags"  name="tags[]"  class="searchInput"   >
    <div class="liner"></div>
    <input type="text"  id="tags1" name="tags[]"  class="searchInput"   >
    <div class="liner"></div>
    <input type="text"  id="tag2" name="tags[]" class="searchInput"  >
    </form> 
    </div>
```

What I am doing wrong here. Please help me.

Comment: Have a look at my example. Might give you some clue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922410/bootstrap-autocomplete-doesnt-load-the-map

Answer (score 0):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/rN4qD/)

As soon as you append the `.searchInput` you can call an `autocomplete` function

```
$('#myTabContent').append(
    '<input id="field" name="tags[]" type="text" class="searchInput" placeholder="Autocomplete" />');
$(".searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

---

[***Fiddle with your HTML Code***](http://jsfiddle.net/rN4qD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

A quite common mistake is to attach an event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

One way to work this out is to attach the event to a parent element, follows a brief example

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="existing" href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

## JS

```
$('a#existing').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').append('<input id="appended" type="text"/>');

    // here we would instanciate autocompleter btw

    $('#appended').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});

// in this case using 

// $('#appended').on('keydown', ... doesnt'work 
// because #appended is not part of the dom

// following should work
// using .one() to detach after first event

$('#container').one('keydown.myEvent', 'input#appended', function(){

    // do something .. for example set autocomplete source ;)

    // from jqueryui api http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
    // setter
    $('input#appended').autocomplete( "option", "source", anotherSource );
});
```

---

#### [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13090731/3739756) will shed some light on the subject

#### [Jqueryui autocomplete api: source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)